# PHP array building

Tags: php, arrays

I am writing a script that collects all the meta data records and generates an array of all the posts and their respective meta data.

Everything seems to work fine except for when I go to push the meta data into the array.  Below is the code that I am using and an example of the output that I get.  What it is

```
 if (mysql_num_rows($currentCourtMetaGet) != null) {
                $metaArray = array();
                while($currentCourseMetaArray = mysql_fetch_array($currentCourseMetaGet)){

                    $metaKey = $currentCourseMetaArray['meta_key'];
                    $metaValue = $currentCourseMetaArray['meta_value'];
                    $metaInfo = "$metaKey => $metaValue";
                    array_push($metaArray, $metaInfo);
                }

                $currentcourse = array(
                    "course_name" => $queryOneResultsArray['post_title'],
                    "course_id" =>  $queryOneResultsArray['id'],
                    "course_meta" => $metaArray         
                );
            array_push($courseArray, $currentcourse);

            }
```

Meta Array output:

```
 [course_meta] => Array
               (
                  [0] => licence_code => 
                  [1] => is_vocable => 0
                  [2] => region => Gladstone
               )
```

My desired output is this.

```
 [course_meta] => Array
               (
                licence_code => 
                is_vocable => 0
                region => Gladstone
               )
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
 if (mysql_num_rows($currentCourtMetaGet) != null) {
        $metaArray = array();
        while($currentCourseMetaArray = mysql_fetch_array($currentCourseMetaGet)){

            $metaKey = $currentCourseMetaArray['meta_key'];
            $metaValue = $currentCourseMetaArray['meta_value'];
            $metaArray[$metaKey] = $metaValue;
        }

        $currentcourse = array(
            "course_name" => $queryOneResultsArray['post_title'],
            "course_id" =>  $queryOneResultsArray['id'],
            "course_meta" => $metaArray         
        );
    array_push($courseArray, $currentcourse);

    }
```

It will output:

```
[course_meta] => Array
           (
            [licence_code] => 
            [is_vocable] => 0
            [region] => Gladstone
           )
```

Arrays are "dumped" in format `[key] => value`. Unless you output them manualy, the exact format you are trying to achieve is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it like this ?

```
$metaArray[$metakey] = $metaInfo;
```

There isn't a way to add values with key using associative arrays, what you've created with

```
$metaInfo = "$metaKey => $metaValue";
```

is a string variable, which has no key